# How to display module Titles Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5

Does anyone know how to turn the title (name) of a module in Joomla 2.5 ? On my site http://www.amidsfo.ru/ now all modules no title (name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From the Joomla Administration page, choose the menu item Extensions/Module Manager
2. Locate and edit the module for which you want the title to appear
3. On the page that appears, in the **Details** pane, directly below the *Title* is *Show Title* - make sure that *Show* is selected

Answer (score 6):

If the show title is enabled and still does not show the title, check your template,

you have to call your module something like this:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="xhtml" />
```

The magic section is style="xhtml", so make sure you have it.